# Match an array of values in url in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have such code:

```
const SEARCH_FORM_PAGES = [ 
  'project/:projectGuid',
  'analysis_group/:analysisGroupGuid',
  'family/:familyGuid',
]

const VariantSearch = ({ match }) =>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={SEARCH_FORM_PAGES.map(pagePath => `${match.url}/${pagePath}`)} component={VariantSearchForm} />,
  </Switch>
```

Now I want to match an array in the `project/:projectGuid` url instead of just a single parameter `:projectGuid`, is it possible? I would have such a url for instance: `project/F001_D1K2,F002_D1K3,F003_D2K5` and I want the part `F001_D1K2,F002_D1K3,F003_D2K5` to be matched and converted into an array `projects` which I would be able to get in the `VariantSearchForm` component.

Answer (score 1):

you can send multiple params like this:

```
/project?items=F001_D1K2&items=F002_D1K3&items=F003_D2K5
```

and then, make it to array, using `query-string` library:

```
import qs from "query-string";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const VariantSearchForm = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation;
  const parsed = qs.parse(search);
  console.log(parsed.items);
  // => ["F001_D1K2", "F002_D1K3", "F003_D2K5"]
};
```